# tagit autocomplete not working on IE9

Tags: jquery, python, forms, jquery-ui-autocomplete, tag-it

I am trying to use the tagit autocomplete(http://webspirited.com/tagit/). The demo page works fine on all browsers. I have a class for autocomplete widgets in forms.py where I have the following code for tagit

```
js = "$('#%s').tagit({\
    tagSource: '%s?type=%s',\
    minLength:2,\
    select:true,\
    initialTags: %s,\
    allowNewTags: false, \
});" % \
(autocomplete_id, url, name, json.dumps(tags));
return u"<ul%s /><script type='text/javascript'>%s</script>" % (flatatt(auto_final_attrs), js)
```

The url is:

```
http://localhost:8000/search/terms/auto?type=naics_code
```

The url is hit and the json response data is present in the IE9 console. However, no autocomplete box appears. This problem is only in IE9. I am using jquery 1.7.1 and jquery-ui-1.8.2-custom. I also tried it with jquery-1.8.18-custom but no changes. If I use some predefined tags array for `tagSource` it works fine in IE9 but if I try to get the data from a url it doesn't work even if I hard code the url.

I want to implement something like Tags option which we have on Stack Overflow while posting a question but the data shown should be from a url. My problem is it doesn't work for IE9 but all other browsers. I didn't try it for older versions of IE since we are implementing the project for IE9+

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this template: http://tag-it-autocomplete.heroku.com/

It works with autocomplete (AJAX one, not just preloaded tags).

Here is the source: https://github.com/makaroni4/tag-it-autocomplete

Tagit config looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mytags").tagit({
    tagSource: function(search, showChoices) {
      var that = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: "/tags/autocomplete.json",
        data: {q: search.term},
        success: function(choices) {
          showChoices(that._subtractArray(choices, that.assignedTags()));
        }
      });
    },
    show_tag_url: "/tags/",
    singleField: true,
    singleFieldNode: $('#submit_tag_names')
  });
});
```

Here **q** - is the parameter of get request, **"/tags/"** - path for each tag, so if you have 'rails' tag will be the link with '/tags/rails' path.

Seems like it is everything you need to work with Tag-it!